# Modal View over UINavigationController - visibleViewController unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, modal-view

I'm using a `RevMob` iOS SDK to show fullscreen ad. This SDK has a built-in pop-up view as a fullscreen modal view. The problem is that I'm using a `UINavigationController`, and issuing this:

```
"[RevMobFullscreenViewController visibleViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
```

The problem appears only in iOS 6. It is everything okay with iOS 5. Help!
The problem appears right after the ad is loaded and it looks like in this moment the modal view tries to pop over the `UINavigationController` and crashes.

Comment: Seems like maybe something's going on with RevMobFullscreenViewController not actually being a NavigationController in this instance? What happens if you print [RevMobFullscreenViewController class] before you present it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the key point.
I had this in my AppDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return [[(UINavigationController *)window.rootViewController visibleViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

And that was the root of all evil. Removed = fixed :)

Thanks to all!